# Issue with first time login/getting to boot menu

Tags: boot, login, password

Recently, I reinstalled Ubuntu as it was just, not happy. I noticed that Ubuntu had updated from 12.04 to 13.something, I can't recall.

Once booting, I immediately noticed a change. In 12, it automatically gave me an account with my name, where I put in my password.

In 13, however, it gives me a login, where I put in my username, then my password. That's fine, I can do that.

Except, there seems to be a problem. From what I can tell, Ubuntu seems to have forgotten to make a default administrator account.

At least, that's my understanding of the situation. I logged in with guest session and went to accounts, and it seemed that the only account there was, was the guest session.

After some searching, I came across various fixes. I had planned to go into recovery and use the following commands:

Useradd username -m -s /bin/bash
Passwd username
Adduser username sudo

Or at least

ls /home

To check if there really was an admin account.

The issue is, holding left shift to go to the boot menu.

When I select Ubuntu from the bootloader, I have tried numerous times with different timings to hold "shift", but the issue is, instead of bringing up this lovely little screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/76OWe.png

I get a bare, black screen, with a underscore flashing at the top left corner. It does that for several moments and then the OS crashes, and I have to press the on button again.

If I can get to the boot menu, I think I'm golden.

I couldn't find anything else on this, so excuse me if I missed out.

All best, thanks in advance.

Comment: Er hrm 13.something probably means 13.04, which is unsupported by Ask Ubuntu since it is a development release.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this may be an issue with grub after the installation of a new OS. I'd try booting from a live USB and install boot-repair, select the simple recommended settings, and see if things work out. More info here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Strange that it's an alpha build, I used the same installer than previously downloaded Ubuntu. Excuse the duplicate, my searching skills are apparently not as good as I thought they were.